# Handling Visualforce StandardController.save() exceptions

Tags: visualforce, exception, standardcontroller

When the save() method is called on a StandardController any exception thrown (e.g. before-insert validation) becomes uncatchable. Instead the controller automatically adds it to the ApexMessages section of the page.

I want to convert the exception into a user-friendly message before adding it to the page. I thought maybe after calling save() I could inspect the resulting PageReference to see if the exception is in it but I don't even get past the save() call.

What's the correct way of doing this?

Comment: Just write your own.

Comment: in your controller extension, add a `PageReference save() { ..}` method that does DML on the controller's sobject (obtained via `getRecord()`) and catch exception

Comment: I'd suggest fixing your triggers so they don't cause exceptions.

Comment: Yes. But my thinking was "if the method is already there I might as well use it. But am I using it correctly?". This is not an XY problem. To me it seems odd to automatically add errors to the view without leaving any trace behind in Apex. As for triggers, they may be preexisting and not even written by us.